# Why won't iPhone charge?

Tags: iphone, ios, charging, power, power-management

I have an iPhone 13 Pro, it is running iOS 15.4. It will only charge when it's dead, and even then it charges really slowly. It only will charge to 1% and then stops charging. I have tried restarting the phone,2 wireless chargers, 3 lightning cables and no luck.

Comment: Have you looked in the iPhone's charge port to see if there's any debris in there that would block/impair the charging?  Otherwise, if it's still under AppleCare you should have Apple look at it.

Comment: Seems your iPhone has a hardware problem.